# ForEach over Object error

Tags: c#, .net, exception, foreach, ienumerable

I have a query in a method so I can call i from multiple places like so:

```
private object GetData(ProfilePropertyDefinition lProfileProperty)
{   
    return from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
           join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Id equals c["contactid"] into opp
           from o in opp.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where ((EntityReference)r["new_channelpartner"]).Id.Equals(lProfileProperty.PropertyValue) && ((OptionSetValue)r["new_leadstatus"]).Equals("100000002")
           select new
           {
               OpportunityId = !r.Contains("opportunityid") ? string.Empty : r["opportunityid"],
               CustomerId = !r.Contains("customerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["customerid"]).Name,
               Priority = !r.Contains("opportunityratingcode") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["opportunityratingcode"],
               ContactName = !r.Contains("new_contact") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Name,
           };
}
```

Then in another method I call the query method like so and try to loop through it:

```
var exportData = GetData(lProfileProperty);
foreach (var lItem in exportData)
{
}
```

Then in the same method when I try to loop through the results I keep getting this error on the foreach:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Any idea what would cause and how to fix it, I'm stumped.

EDIT:

Took Jon's advice and for the most part it seems to be working. But when I call the method like: `GetData<lProfileProperty.PropertyValue>;` It says lProfileProperty can't be found. But it's there. Any ideas?

**EDIT 2:** I have everything from Jon's example in place. I'm getting one error though: On `foreach (GridDataItem lItem in exportData)` it is saying Error 67  Cannot convert type 'DotNetNuke.Modules.CPCLeadShare.View.Foo' to 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataItem' any ideas on how to fix this? I need to be able to use the DGridDataItem so I can access the "Cells".

Comment: `GetData<lProfileProperty.PropertyValue>;` is not a method call.  You need to use `()` for a method call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is telling you what the problem is: you cannot iterate over something that has a static type of `object`. Fix the return type of your `GetData` method to return something that implements `IEnumerable`.

Since you are returning a sequence of an anonymous type, you could do this simply by changing the code to

```
private IEnumerable GetData(ProfilePropertyDefinition lProfileProperty)
```

However, you would then be unable to access the properties in the objects except by reflection. To fix that as well, you need to create a new class and return instances of that. For example:

```
class Foo {
    public string OpportunityId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
private IEnumerable<Foo> GetData(ProfilePropertyDefinition lProfileProperty) {
   // ...
   select new Foo
       { 
           OpportunityId = !r.Contains("opportunityid") ? string.Empty : r["opportunityid"], 
           CustomerId = !r.Contains("customerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["customerid"]).Name, 
           Priority = !r.Contains("opportunityratingcode") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["opportunityratingcode"], 
           ContactName = !r.Contains("new_contact") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Name, 
       }; 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Worked well, thanks! In the for each i am casting the variable to GridDataItem and I get Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType7`25[System.Object,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object,System.Object,System.Object,System.Object,System.Object,System.Object,System.Object,System.Object,System.Object,System.Object,System.String,System.String]' to type 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridDataItem'. Any idea on that? Sorry that was long. Thanks!

Comment: @Justin read Jon's answer.  The relevant bit: "To fix that as well, you need to create a new class and return instances of that. For example:"

Comment: @phoog thanks, but I still get that error I posted above your comment using Jon's code.

Comment: @Justin then you must have misunderstood something about Jon's code, because he is telling you not to use anonymous types, but the error message shows that you are using an anonymous type.  Edit your question and add your current code, and perhaps the reason for the disconnect will become clear.

Comment: @phoog thanks, I got it working, but how do I call the GetData() when I use GetData<lProfileProperty.PropertyValue>; It says lProfileProperty can't be found. But it's there.

Comment: What happens if you don't know what the values will be before hand and so can't create a class? For instance if you were looping through an XML file.

Comment: @hoakey: It depends on how much you do know about the XML and what you intend to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

Your method returns an `object`. object doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. You're also not going to be able to cast to `IEnumerable<T>` because your method uses an anonymous type.

Your only option is to create a concrete class for the return type of the method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a type of GetData() that implements IEnumerable. I suggest chaining object in the method signature to IEnumerable.

IEnumerable contains a method GetEnumerator() which allows the foreach loop to work.

Answer (score 1):

your method is returning `object`, not a collection or list of any kind

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because the variable received from `GetData(...)` is of type `object`. You cannot enumerate an `object` because it is what it is - an object and not a collection. To enumerate the result of the method call, you need to cast the object into a type that *is* a collection, and therefore *has* a `GetEnumerator(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `IEnumerable<Some>` to be able loop over it. Currently you return just `object`.

But you can't return an anonymous type from a method, so you need to declare a specific type:

```
class Foo
{
    ...
}

private IEnumereable<Foo> GetDate()
{
    return ...
           select new Foo
           {
               ...
           };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private object GetData(ProfilePropertyDefinition lProfileProperty)
{
    var result = from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
                 join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Id equals c["contactid"] into opp
                 from o in opp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where ((EntityReference)r["new_channelpartner"]).Id.Equals(lProfileProperty.PropertyValue) && ((OptionSetValue)r["new_leadstatus"]).Equals("100000002")
                 select new    
                 {
                     OpportunityId = !r.Contains("opportunityid") ? string.Empty : r["opportunityid"],
                     CustomerId = !r.Contains("customerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["customerid"]).Name,
                     Priority = !r.Contains("opportunityratingcode") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["opportunityratingcode"],
                     ContactName = !r.Contains("new_contact") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Name,
                 });

                 return result.ToList();
    }
```

and

```
foreach (var lItem in List<object>GetData(lProfileProperty))
{
}
```

and add some class

```
select new  [YouClassView]  
                 {
                     OpportunityId = !r.Contains("opportunityid") ? string.Empty : r["opportunityid"],
                     Custo
```

Comment: You will not be able to access any property of the resulting anonymous type.